# memcached not releasing unused pages from a slab and results in evictions from other slabs

Tags: cache, centos-7

We are running into a situation where evictions are happening in certain slabs even if there is enough memory allocated to memcached but memcached not releasing/rebalancing unused pages from other slabs.

memcached version: 1.4.15

Here is the memcached-tool-ng (third party tool with a little more info about memstats) output.

```
   #  Item_Size    Max_age   Pages     Count   Used Mem     To Store   Efficiency  Evicted  Evict_Time  OOM
  10       6.9K      1583s       1         2    1.00 MB     12.99 KB       1.27 %        0           0   0
  11      11.1K       480s      83      1890   83.00 MB     17.38 MB      20.94 %   282249         480   0
  12      17.8K       479s      57      1156   57.00 MB     19.67 MB      34.51 %  6959481         479   0
  13      28.4K       480s    1052      7277    1.03 GB    136.18 MB      12.94 %   941078         480   0
  14      45.5K        27s     562        17  562.00 MB    536.25 KB       0.09 %   114861          22   0
  15      72.7K        21s     574         2  574.00 MB    125.03 KB       0.02 %     2615          18   0
  16     116.4K     30055s     790       300  790.00 MB     25.96 MB       3.29 %    34786          22   0
  17     186.2K     30230s    1823      1433    1.78 GB    187.89 MB      10.31 %    21823          22   0
  18     297.9K     30201s    2604        26    2.54 GB      4.91 MB       0.19 %     1373          25   0
  19     476.7K     35234s    1322         2    1.29 GB    615.39 KB       0.05 %        0           0   0
  20    1024.0K         0s       2         0    2.00 MB          0 b       0.00 %        0           0   0

Total used memory: 8.66 GB (for 393.24 MB of data)
Global efficiency:  4.43 %

Total used memory: 8.66 GB (for 393.24 MB of data)
Global efficiency:  4.43 %
```

Looking at the Page count and the object count, it is evident that lot of memory is being wasted in higher slabs. Consider slab 18 or 19, in slab 18 there are only 26 objects, assuming we might need at the max of 13 pages to accommodate these object, the total pages allocated are 2604.

Our application typically sets TTL of not more than 480 sec on any object, however the max age in higher slabs are too high, also the denser(lower) slabs are seeing lot evictions.

Can somebody explain why Memcached is not reclaiming the unused pages from higher slabs and allocating it to the slabs where more pages are required.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Its a CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 machine

Comment: Don't remember 1.4 having automatic slab re-balancing just some manual methods.   It is listed as a new feature for 1.5 : https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/ReleaseNotes150

Comment: @Brian What do you mean by manual methods, how can we do that?